# copy whole line to system clipboard even if not visible on screen

Tags: cut-copy-paste

How to copy a whole long line to system clipboard even if the full line is not visible on screen?

The line is very lengthy that it doesn't fit the screen even with wrap on. I need to the copy this whole line to a text editor on the windows machine. The vim editor is opened from a remote RHEL 8.4 server on a putty terminal.

I have tried "shift+v" followed by "ctrl+c". But it seems to select only the text visisble on the screen.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You should add more specific detail - is the line you want in the same/different buffer? Do you know it's line number? Or do you just know what it contains? Without these details we all have to guess your problem...

Comment: I guess it is about using terminal copy not vim's clipboard register.

Comment: Try `:set wrap`. Then you will see `<S-v>` highlights the FULL text line, not just the screen line.

Answer (score 3):

Locally, if your vim has clipboard support, `"*yy` (or `"+` as you prefer) should work. If you haven't mapped `Y`, then `"*Y` is also an option (some, including me, have gotten used to `Y` being more like `C` and `D`; that is, equivalent to `y$` instead of `yy`, just like `C` is `c$` and `D` is `d$`). There's also `:yank *`, which can be abbreviated to `:y*`.

On a remote instance, the situation is more complicated. Instead, I would open vim locally and use netrw to edit a remote file; then the local method works fine.